# Moses - Online Integration

Tags: localization, machine-translation, moses

We're actually looking to integrate Moses into our localization workflow. Our application is in Java and we're looking at using Moses' functionalities using xml-rpc calls.

Specifically, we're looking at APIs for:

1. Incremental training (i.e. Avoid having to retrain the model
   from scratch every time we wish to use some new training data)
2. Domain-specific training (i.e. It should maintain separate
   phrase tables for each domain that the input data belongs),
3. Decoding

The tutorial says that these can be achieved via xml-rpc calls. But, I don't find any examples or clear ways to do them. Can someone please provide some examples?

Also, I would like to know if the training and decoding phases can be done in a 
distributed manner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this question is perfectly suitable for moses mailing list: 
http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.MailingLists

moses server documentation (via xml-rpc):

http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.AdvancedFeatures#ntoc28

However, I have better experiences with: `moses/contrib/web/bin/daemon.pl` which makes server as well, and you communicate via `tcp` stream.

General examples are harder to find(everyone has different enviroment,...), but make your question more specific and send it to moses mailing list. (e.g. someone had a problem with server installation: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.nlp.moses.user/7242 )